# Microsoft.NetNative compile results in warning ILT0003

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to build my first UWP app with Xamarin.Forms in it. But when I compile in release build I get always this bunch of errors and starting the app in this state results in a splash screen lock.

```
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'FormsApp.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'DarkThemeResources.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'DefaultThemeResources.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'LightThemeResources.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'ContactPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'DataPrivacySettingsPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'HelpPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'ImageViewerPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'InAppPurchasingPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'InformationPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'LegalContentPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Xamarin.Forms.CheckBox' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'MapDownloadPage.InitializeComponent()'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'MapPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'MasterPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'SettingsPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'StatisticPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'WebViewPage.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'MainMenuViewCell.InitializeComponent()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'ResourceLoader.ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
3>  Cleaning up unreferenced code
3>  Generating native code
3>  Generating fixups for native code
```

I have no clue what todo with this error. Can I avoid this error somehow? Or do I just have to avoid "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" option?

Comment: Can it run in the debug model?  I suppose `UWPNuGetPackages` does not support release mode. Could show more about `UWPNuGetPackages` ?

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT as mentioned this only happens in Release Build. And why should it not be able to run a release build? This makes no sense. There is no reason to publish a Debug Build to the store so if a Release Build is not supported, the whole function should not exists at all. Also the message clearly says that the linker has screwed the build up (because InitializeComponent() can't be missed) so the only question is, how to prevent the linker from this behavour.

Comment: Yep, I could get your point, Could share a [mcve] for us?

Comment: Well if I know what causes the issue I could share a example and probably fix the issue. But I added UWP after a half year of development to this project so I have no idea which components are causing the issue. Would be nice if there is some kind of hint in the log or that the VS can attach to a release build to identify the issue... Even with Console prints none of my methods is getting called. Not even the constructor of the app class..

Comment: I suppose that one of the nuget package  you referenced caused this problem. Could share nuget packages you used?

Comment: I guess it is easier to share the whole UWP *.csproj file: https://pastebin.com/a0ZvMAUi I already checked both used beta packages but those two seems to be fine. From any release package I would assume the same.

Comment: I found two beta version package you used `<PackageReference Include="Mapsui.Forms">
      <Version>2.0.0-beta.25</Version>
    </PackageReference>`  and  `<PackageReference Include="Plugin.InAppBilling">
      <Version>2.1.0.187-beta</Version>
    </PackageReference>` could you use stable version test?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT as already mentioned I can exclude both package as cause for the issue. I use the beta version of these two for some new features and the issue also happens with their latest release counterparts.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT hmm after closing VS, deleting obj and bin the project now fails with this exception at start in release build. https://pastebin.com/aTHxwAj4 based on this, it seems like `LabelHtml.Forms.Plugin` or `MvvmCross`has a problem.

Comment: Could try to modify to another stable version for `LabelHtml.Forms.Plugin` `MvvmCros` ?

Comment: have you ever found the reason?